# Table left join with itself returning NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like

```
Tdate          Symbol       new_close
20100110        xxx           1.2
20100111        xxx           1.3
...
20100110        yyy           1.1
20100111        yyy           1.5
```

Where Tdate was stored as integer and updated per day for each symbol. I want generate a new table from it by subtracting new_close value to its previous one, which looks like this

```
    Tdate          Symbol       delta
    20100110        xxx           =1.2-1.2
    20100111        xxx           =1.3-1.2
    ...
    20100110        yyy           =1.1-1.1
    20100111        yyy           =1.5-1.1
```

Here is my code

```
with delta as
( select a.Tdate as TDate,  a.Symbol as Symbol,
a.new_close-b.new_close as Pdelta, b.new_close as oldPrice
   from ctsWithSplit a left join ctsWithSplit b
   on a.TDate-b.TDate=1 and a.Symbol=b.Symbol)
```

However, in the new generated table, some delta value is NULL, how to fix it please?

Comment: When your left join doesn't find a matching row in `b` (i.e. on the first Tdate, or where there isn't a Tdate for the preceding day), then `b.new_close` will be NULL, as will the result of the subtraction.  What's supposed to happen when there isn't a relevant Tdate?

Comment: If you want to records equal in both tables, use INNER join instead of LEFT join.

Comment: Look into Lead(), Lag() analytic function if you need to display prev/next value, not joins.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is `TDATE` being stored as a number? Your query will fail to find the previous day when the date is the first of the month - eg: 20150201 - 20150131 = 70, whereas there's only a day between 31st Jan and 1st Feb.

Store dates as `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype, and then you give Oracle a chance at getting the date arithmetic correct.

Perhaps you're after something like:

```
with sample_data as (select to_date('10/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') tdate, 'xxx' symbol, 1.2 new_close from dual union all
                     select to_date('11/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') tdate, 'xxx' symbol, 1.3 new_close from dual union all
                     select to_date('10/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') tdate, 'yyy' symbol, 1.1 new_close from dual union all
                     select to_date('11/01/2010', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') tdate, 'yyy' symbol, 1.5 new_close from dual)
select tdate,
       symbol,
       new_close - lag(new_close, 1, new_close) over (partition by symbol order by tdate) delta
from   sample_data;

TDATE      SYMBOL DELTA
---------- ------ -----
10/01/2010 xxx      0.0
11/01/2010 xxx      0.1
10/01/2010 yyy      0.0
11/01/2010 yyy      0.4
```

If you've never worked with analytic functions, then I suggest you look them up - they're incredibly useful and very powerful.

N.B. If you can't convert your `TDATE` column to be `DATE` datatype, then you need to convert the column into a date in any queries you run by using `to_date()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to load the data from a csv file. How  to convert tdate into the format 10/01/2010 please?

Comment: `to_date('20100110', 'yyyymmdd')`

Comment: So in my query, should I use to_date(Tdate,'yyyymmdd') please? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Yes; you'd at least want to change the `order by tdate` to `order by to_date(tdate, 'yyyymmdd')` in the `over()` clause (and also in the order by clause if you end up wanting your results in date order). However, if at all possible, when you load the data from the csv file, you should store it in the correct datatype. Numbers should be stored in a number datatype, and dates should be date or timestamp. Then you don't have to remember to convert the column to a date every time you query the table.

Answer (score 0):

When your left join doesn't find a matching row in `b` (i.e. on the first `Tdate`, or where there isn't a `Tdate` for the preceding day), then `b.new_close` will be NULL, as will the result of the subtraction.
Try:

```
select
    a.Tdate as TDate,
    a.Symbol as Symbol,
    CASE WHEN b.new_close IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.new_close-b.new_close END as Pdelta,
    b.new_close as oldPrice
from ctsWithSplit a
left join ctsWithSplit b
    on a.TDate-b.TDate=1
    and a.Symbol=b.Symbol
```